# Create Audit Log Script w/ Custom Dates

Tags: powershell, auditing, script

The following PowerShell script pulls all the content from a specified SharePoint site and creates an audit log for all versions and dates. My Question is how would I implement a Start/End date? For example I would like to view only the items between 10/3/2014 and 10/5/2014.

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://<SharePoint Site>
ForEach($list in $web.Lists) 
{
 ForEach($item in $list.Items)
 { 
  ForEach($version in $item.Versions)
  {    
    $fullURL = "$($web.URL)$($list.URL)/$($version.URL)"    
    "{0}`t{1}`t{2}`t{3}`t{4}" -f $fullURL, $version.VersionLabel, $version.CreatedBy.User.UserLogin, $version.Created, $list.BaseType  | out-file Versions.csv -Append  
  }   
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://devintranet.tokiomillennium.com/operations/claims
$startDate = [datetime]::ParseExact("10/03/14", "dd/MM/yy", $null)
$endDate = [datetime]::ParseExact("10/05/14", "dd/MM/yy", $null)

ForEach($list in $web.Lists) 
{
    ForEach($item in $list.Items)
    { 
        ForEach($version in $item.Versions)
        {    
            if($version.Created -ge $startDate -AND $version.Created -le $endDate)
            {
                $fullURL = "$($web.URL)$($list.URL)/$($version.URL)"        
                "{0}`t{1}`t{2}`t{3}`t{4}" -f $fullURL, $version.VersionLabel, $version.CreatedBy.User.UserLogin, $version.Created, $list.BaseType  | out-file Versions.csv -Append  
            }
        }   
    } 
}
```

Comment: Amal, thanks for the response. When I test it out I get the following error: Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar."